# Gostaria de saber se é possível ter uma máscara de telefone em um text View

Tags: android, listview, mask, textview

Gostaria de saber  como fazer para ter uma máscara de telefone em um campo text View.

No meu caso tenho uma listView com contatos onde em cada linha dessa listView aparece o nome do contato e o telefone.

Gostaria que o telefone ficasse com a máscara `(##)####-####`.

Lembrando que no cadastro de cliente a máscara já funciona.

Desde já agradeço a quem, de qualquer forma, puder ajudar de forma clara e específica pois não tenho muita experiência. Muito Obrigado.

Meu código de Cadastro de cliente:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ClienteDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;

 public class CadCliente extends Activity {

EditText edId, edNome, edEmail, edTelefone, edEndereco, edCpf, edRg;
ClienteDao cliDao;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad_clientes);
    edId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdId);
    edNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdNome);
    edEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdEmail);
    edTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdTelefone);
    edTelefone.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("(##)####-####", edTelefone));
    edEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdEndereco);
    edCpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdCpf);
    edCpf.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("###.###.###-##", edCpf));
    edRg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdRg);
    edRg.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.###.###-#", edRg));

    Cliente clienteRecebido = (Cliente) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Cliente");
    if (clienteRecebido != null) {
        montaTela(clienteRecebido);
    } else {
        montaTela(new Cliente());
    }

    Button btnSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);
    btnSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cliente cli = new Cliente();
            cli.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            cli.setNome(edNome.getText().toString());
            cli.setEmail(edEmail.getText().toString());
            cli.setTelefone(Mask.unmask(edTelefone.getText().toString()));
            cli.setEndereco(edEndereco.getText().toString());
            cli.setRg(Mask.unmask(edRg.getText().toString()));
            cli.setCpf(Mask.unmask(edCpf.getText().toString()));

            if (cli.getNome().equals("")) {
                edNome.setError("Preencha o nome");
                return;

            } else if (cli.getEmail().equals("")) {
                edEmail.setError("Preencha o Email");
                return; 

            } else if (cli.getTelefone().equals("")) {
                edTelefone.setError("Preencha o telefone");
                return; 

            } else if (cli.getEndereco().equals("")) {
                edEndereco.setError("Preencha o endereço");
                return; 

            } else if (cli.getRg().equals("")) {
                edRg.setError("Preencha o RG");
                return; 

            } else if (cli.getCpf().equals("")) {
                edCpf.setError("Preencha o CPF"); 
                return; 
            }

            if (cli.getId() > 0) {
                getCliDao().alterar(cli);
                ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Salvo com Sucesso",
                        ToastManager.INFORMATION);
            } else {
                getCliDao().inserirCliente(cli);
                ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Salvo com Sucesso",
                        ToastManager.INFORMATION);
            }
        }

    }
    );

    Button btnLimpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLimpar);

    btnLimpar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            montaTela(new Cliente());
        }
    }
    );

    Button btExcluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btExcluir);
    btExcluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Cliente cli = new Cliente();
            cli.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            cli.setNome(edNome.getText().toString());
            cli.setEmail(edEmail.getText().toString());
            cli.setTelefone(edTelefone.getText().toString());
            cli.setEndereco(edEndereco.getText().toString());
            cli.setRg(edRg.getText().toString());
            cli.setCpf(edCpf.getText().toString());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadCliente.this);
            builder.setTitle("Deseja Excluir?");
            builder.setMessage("O Cliente será deletado!");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getCliDao().excluir(cli);
                    montaTela(new Cliente());
                    ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Cliente excluído",
                            ToastManager.INFORMATION);

                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Cancelado",
                            ToastManager.INFORMATION);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    });

}

private void montaTela(Cliente cliente) {
    edId.setText(String.valueOf(cliente.getId()));
    edNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
    edEmail.setText(cliente.getEmail());
    edTelefone.setText(cliente.getTelefone());
    edEndereco.setText(cliente.getEndereco());
    edCpf.setText(cliente.getCpf());
    edRg.setText(cliente.getRg());

}

public ClienteDao getCliDao() {
    if (cliDao == null) {
        cliDao = new ClienteDao();
    }
    return cliDao;
}

}
```

Meu Cliente Adapter:

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;
 import br.gestaoBd.Mask;
 import br.gestaoBd.R;
 import java.util.List;

 public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

private Context context;
private List<Cliente> clientes;

public ClienteAdapter(Context context, List<Cliente> clientes) {
    this.context = context;
    this.clientes = clientes;
}

public int getCount() {
    return clientes.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return clientes.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return clientes.get(position).getId();
}  


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cliente cliente = clientes.get(position);

    LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = layout.inflate(R.layout.linhacli, null);

    Log.i("AULA", "Montou:" + cliente.getNome());
    Log.e("ERRO", "Valor da variavel estava nullo!");

    ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sem_foto);

    TextView edNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    edNome.setText(cliente.getNome());

    TextView lblTelefone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    lblTelefone.setText(cliente.getTelefone());



    return view;
}
}
```

Minha Lista de clientes;

```
 import static android.R.id.list;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ClienteDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;
 import br.gestaoBd.listaadapters.ClienteAdapter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;


 public class ListClientes extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView lista;
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_clientes);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    atualizar(null);
}

public void atualizar(View view) {
    ClienteDao cliDao = new ClienteDao();

    clientes = cliDao.getListagem();
    lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));

}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent cadClienteIntent = new Intent(this, CadCliente.class);
    cadClienteIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadClienteIntent);
    return true;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    Intent cadPedidoIntent = new Intent(this, CadPedido.class);
    cadPedidoIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadPedidoIntent);

}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para isto, vamos fazer igual ao `TextView`.

Mas ao invés de passar em um `changeListener`, vamos passar a `String` pronta!

Na sua classe `Mask`,implemente o seguinte método:

```
  public static String addMask(final String textoAFormatar, final String mask){
        String formatado = "";
        int i = 0; 
        // vamos iterar a mascara, para descobrir quais caracteres vamos adicionar e quando...
        for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) { 
            if (m != '#') { // se não for um #, vamos colocar o caracter informado na máscara 
                formatado += m;
                continue; 
            }
            // Senão colocamos o valor que será formatado
            try {
                formatado += textoAFormatar.charAt(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return formatado;
    }
```

No seu cliente adapter:

```
  TextView lblTelefone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   lblTelefone.setText(Mask.addMask(cliente.getTelefone(), "(##)####-####"));
```

Comment: Perfeito! @Thiago Luiz Domacoski . Muito Obrigado