# Como faço para aplicar máscara monetária na minha listView?

Tags: java, android, listview, mask

Gostaria de saber como implemento minha máscara monetária na `ListView` de produtos. Peço que sejam o mais específicos e detalhados pois não tenho muita experiência. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class ProdutoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Produto> produtos;

    public ProdutoAdapter(Context context, List<Produto> produtos) {
        this.context = context;
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return produtos.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return produtos.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return produtos.get(position).getId();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Produto produto = produtos.get(position);

        LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layout.inflate(R.layout.linhapro, null);

        ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgProduto);
        imgImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sem_foto);

        TextView edDescricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        edDescricao.setText(produto.getDescricao());

        TextView edPreco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        edPreco.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Da mesma forma que você fez com o [TextView](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106951/gostaria-de-saber-se-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-ter-uma-m%C3%A1scara-de-telefone-em-um-text-view/106961#106961)

Comment: ´ TextView edPreco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);     edPreco.setText(Mask.addMask(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda(),  "R$#.###.###,##")));
        return view; ´ fiz dessa maneira que é a mesma do TextView porém está aparecendo um erro : no suitable method found for valueOf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `NumberFormat` do próprio Java para isso, através do método `getCurrencyInstance(Locale)`.

Em `Locale`, você precisa passar em qual o formato da moeda de acordo com sua localidade. No caso para o Brasil:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
```

No caso para Portugal:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "PT");
```

Agora, só passar seu `Locale` como parametro:

```
double valor = produto.getPrecoDeVenda();

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
String valorFormatado = formatter.format(valor);
edPreco.setText(valorFormatado);
```