# EditText - mais de um Listener?

Tags: java, android

Estou dando prosseguimento a um projeto que faz pedidos no Android, e me deparei com a formatação monetária no `EditText`

Pesquisando consegui achar uma classe que está funcionando tranquilo, mais porque eu tô falando de máscara?

Então meu `layout` tem Valor Unitário, Quantidade, Desconto e Valor Total
Quantidade e desconto são campos que ao modifica-los preciso atualizar o Valor Total.

Minha dúvida deve ser daquelas bem básica mais não estou conseguindo passar adiante, com certeza deve esta me faltando o fundamental do java.

Não consigo calcular porque apliquei no componente Quantidade e desconto o evento `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher())` aplicando a máscara
como posso ter outro Listener com um propósito de calcular o valor Total ?

Não ficaria correto colocar um botão apenas para a finalidade de mostrar o valor total, o correto seria quando o usuário interagisse com o campo isto acontecer

Comment: [Leia esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108972/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-aplicar-m%C3%A1scara-monet%C3%A1ria-na-minha-listview?noredirect=1#comment225419_108972) que irá lhe ajudar!

Comment: Olá Thiago boa tarde. Não tem muito a ver com o que eu perguntei, mascara foi comentado em ambos? Sim foi mais a questão é poder colocar outro listener pois já existe um para a mascara, mais eu preciso de outro para quando o valor for digitado chamar um método para calcular o valor total.

Comment: Olá! Não em relação a máscara, e sim em utilizar outro listener. Não se pode usar o mesmo Listener (a não ser q adapte para realizar as duas funções). Note que a pergunta possui uma outra marcada como duplicada. Esta também aborda o mesmo tema!

Comment: Olá Boa tarde. bem meu caro não entendi, eu fui no link e li a outra pergunta mais ela tem a ver com mascara, a minha pergunta não tem a ver com mascara e sim em se existe como colocar outro listener